# Angular 5 - Can't output an Image using src?

Tags: html, angular, src

I am using **Angular 5** in an attempt to display an image that I have sat in a file 2 directories up from where I have the HTML, however I simply get the blank image box and an error in the console of:

> GET http://localhost:4200/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I am attempting to output via the code:

```
<img src="../../logo.jpg">
```

I have tested by placing a placeholder.it image within the `src` which worked perfectly... For some reason this will not?

Comment: You have to copy the image using `.angular-cli.json`. Your image is missing from the output folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [@angular/cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) you'd need to place your images under `/src/assets/` in line with the `.angular-cli.json` asset configuration. You can then just use the image directly such as:

```
<img src="assets/pa-logo.jpg">
```

You can create additional folders under "assets" property in `.angular-cli.json` for additional control/organization as necessary:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "foobar",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Usage after you placed `pa-logo.jpg` in the this hypothetical `foobar` folder:

```
<img src="foobar/pa-logo.jpg">
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Aha! What a strange thing to happen. Why wouldn't you be able to use an image based anywhere? :-(

Comment: Effectively behind the scenes webpack is resolving paths as part of build process. You could alternatively use path relative to the root I believe.